# How to create program to Calculate Resistors in Series using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm newbie in here. i want to create program to calculate resistors in series using HTML & javascript.

I have tried to make it with code below.  there are 2 functions.

first, to create input fields automatically based on how many resistors you wants to input. 
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEdQi.png).( i have created this function ).

and the second function is sum the total values of the input fields that have been created.
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1pQL.png). (  i'm not yet create this function )

how to create this ? could you complate the second function ? or any have other alternative ?

JAVASCRIPT :

```js
< script >
  function display() {
    var y = document.getElementById("form1").angka1.value;
    var x;
    for (x = 1; x <= y; x++) {
      var a = document.getElementById("container");
      var newInput = document.createElement('div');
      newInput.innerHTML = 'R ' + x + ': <input type="text" id="r_' + x + '" name="r_' + x + '"/>';
      a.appendChild(newInput);
    }
  }

function count() {
//this function not yet created
} 
</script>
```

HTML:

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" onsubmit="return false">
  <label for="number">Input Qty of Resistors </label>
  <input type="number" name="angka1">
  <input type="submit" value="Display Input" onclick="display()">
  <div id="container"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Count" onclick="count()">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working demo of what you want to achieve. [Click Here](https://js.do/rmohan20195/254860)

Note that here in demo I have use **JQuery** so please include jquery file.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label for="number">Input Qty of Resistors </label>
    <input type="number" id="angka1" />
    <input type="button" value="Display Input" onclick="display()" />
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Count" onclick="count()" />
    <label id="totalCount"></label>
  function display() {
            document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "";
            var y = document.getElementById("angka1").value;
            var x;
            for (x = 1; x <= y; x++) {
                var a = document.getElementById("container");
                var newInput = document.createElement('div');
                newInput.innerHTML = 'R ' + x + ': <input type="number" id="r_' + x + '" name="r_' + x + '" />';

                a.appendChild(newInput);
            }
        }


  function count() {
            console.log("Count function is called.");
            var total = 0;
            $("#container input").each(function () {
                total += Number($(this).val().trim());
                console.log(total);
            });
            document.getElementById("totalCount").innerHTML = total;
        }
```

Hope that will work for you.

Comment: Glad to hear that. You can vote up the answer so that other people can also use the given answer if they have same query.

Comment: Please also mark the answer correct if it is helpful.